# How to design mutual inductor in proteus for wireless charging?

Tags: wireless, inductor, proteus

While designing the wireless charger, i've designed the circuitry in proteus. And it begins with the use of the dc voltage, then the oscillator and finally the transmitter circuitry and the receiver circuit.The problem arises how to design the mutual inductance between the transmitter and receiver circuit in the proteus.I can't find out the right component for it in proteus. What might be a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to build the model yourself, according to the circuit below.

The Primary Inductance can be simply the inductance of your primary coil on its own. So either model it, calculate it from the dimensions and number of turns, or simply wind the thing and measure it.

The Leakage Inductance is measured the same way, i.e. by measuring the primary inductance again, but with the secondary coil in its proper place with its output short circuited. Modelling it or calculating it is likely to be hit or miss, and its actual value will be critically dependent on the relative positions of the two coils, so most easily determined by actual measurement.

The transformer is an "ideal transformer" whose turns ratio is the same as your two coils.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr5ozZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An accurate model would also include both winding resistances and capacitances, but this should serve as a starting point.